# Numpy operation to expand array into sequential slices of given length?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

`my_function` must expand a 1D numpy array to a 2D numpy array, with the 2nd axis containing the slices of `length` starting from the first index until the end. Example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
print (my_function(a, length=3))
```

Expected output

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

I can achieve this using a `for` loop, but I was wondering if there is a numpy vectorization technique for this.

```
def my_function(a, length):
    b = np.zeros((len(a)-(length-1), length))
    for i in range(len(b)):
        b[i] = a[i:i+length]
    return b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're careful with the math and heed the warningin the docs, you can use [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html). You need to calculate the correct dimensions for your array so you don't overflow. Also note that `as_strided()` shares memory, so you will multiple references to the same memory in the final output. (You can of course, copy this to a new array).

```
>> import numpy as np

>> def my_function(a, length):
    stride = a.strides[0]
    l = len(a) - length + 1
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (l, length), (stride,stride) )

>> np.array(my_function(np.arange(10), 3))

array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [7, 8, 9]])

>> np.array(my_function(np.arange(15), 7))

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Comment: Great idea, and the fastest solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this function?

```
import numpy as np
def my_function(a, length):
    result = []
    for i in range(length):
        result.append(a + i)
    return np.vstack(result).T[:len(a) - length + 1]

a = np.arange(10)
length = 3
my_function(a, length)
```